# How to create content type using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Using the web interface, I can create different "content types" derived from the parent system's content types.

I am trying to create such a content type using Microsoft Graph but I failed to find any documentation.

Can anyone provide me with a proper solution?

Answer (score -4):

Check whether the content type already exists. If it does not exist, create the content type and add it to the ContentTypes collection for the Web, as shown in the following example.

```
public static readonly SPContentTypeId myContentTypeId
  = new SPContentTypeId("0x010100FA0963FA69A646AA916D2E41284FC9D9");

SPContentType myContentType = web.ContentTypes[myContentTypeId];

if (myContentType == null)
{
  myContentType = new SPContentType(myContentTypeId,
    web.ContentTypes, "My Content Type");

  web.ContentTypes.Add(myContentType);
}
```